# Gramians of similar systems

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

The following lemma is stated without proof in the lectures notes on Model Reduction by M. Voigt (available [here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/voigt/Modellreduktion_SoSe19/Notes_ModelReduction.pdf))

Lemma 4.4 Let $[A,B,C,D]\in\Sigma_{n,m,p}$ be asymptotically stable. Let $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be invertible and define $[\tilde A,\tilde B, \tilde C,\tilde D]:=[T^{-1}AT,T^{-1}B,CT,D]$. Then,

1. $P$ is the controllability Gramian of $[A,B,C,D]$, if and only if $\tilde P:=T^{-1}PT^{-T}$ is the controllability Gramian of $[\tilde A,\tilde B, \tilde C,\tilde D]$.
2. $Q$ is the observability Gramian of $[A,B,C,D]$, if and only if $\tilde Q:=T^{T}QT^{-1}$ is the observability Gramian of $[\tilde A,\tilde B, \tilde C,\tilde D]$.

I am not sure on how to prove this result. Would anyone has some hints? Thanks!

My idea for the 1. question;

Using the Lyapunov equations,
$$\tilde{A} \tilde{P} + \tilde{P} \tilde{A}^T = -\tilde{B}\tilde{B}^T 
\hspace{1.6cm} (1)$$
$$A P + P A^T = -B B^T 
\hspace{1.6cm} (2)$$
$$\tilde{A} = T^{-1} A T; \hspace{0.6cm} \tilde{B} = T^{-1}B
\hspace{1.6cm} (3)$$
Then inserting (3) into (1) we have,
$$T^{-1} A T \tilde{P} + \tilde{P} {(T^{-1} A T)}^T = -T^{-1}B {(T^{-1}B)}^T$$
$$T^{-1} A T \tilde{P} + \tilde{P} T^T A^T T^{-T} = -T^{-1}B B^T T^{-T}$$

Now we use (2) on the right side and obtain,
$$ T^{-1} A T \tilde{P} + \tilde{P} T^T A^T T^{-T} = T^{-1} (A P + P A^T ) T^{-T}$$
By multiplying the whole equation with $T$ on the left and $T^T$ on the right we have,
$$ A T \tilde{P} T^T + T \tilde{P} T^T A^T  = A P + P A^T$$
If we take a substitution $M = T \tilde{P} T^T$,
$$ A M + M A^T  = A P + P A^T$$
We clearly see that this is,
$$M = P = T \tilde{P} T^T$$
Finally, by multiplying the whole equation with $T^{-1}$ on the left and $T^{-T}$ on the right we obtain,
$$ T^{-1} P T^{-T} = \tilde{P}$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Use the definition of the gramians in terms of Lyapunov equations and just do some algebra.

Comment: @larasupernovae Please update your question with your attempt and also use the same notations as in the question. If you use new notation, please define what it is. Please also make sure to write clearly what you are doing.

Comment: @KBS got it will do! thank you!

Comment: @larasupernovae There are problems in your solution. First of all, you consider the inverse of $A$ while this matrix may not be invertible. It is also unclear to me how you get $A \tilde{P} + \tilde{P} A^T = -T^{-1}B B^T T^{-T}$ from the previous expression. Finally, your approach is more complicated than it should be. In fact, there is only one operation to perform on $T^{-1} A T \tilde{P} + \tilde{P} T^T A^T T^{-T} = -T^{-1}B B^T T^{-T}$ to get the desired proof.

Comment: You're right, I took the assumtion that A is invertible / non-singular, which might not be correct, I will correct everything now, it is much simpler I complicated things quite a bit, thank you so much @KBS!!!

Comment: @KBS By the lemma $A$ is assumed to be Hurwitz (asymptotically stable) so it must be invertible as far as I can see (no zero eigenvalue).

Comment: @SampleTime Yes, it is correct, I missed that. But that does not change the fact that the proof can be made much simpler.